# get occurrences of a list in an array - python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
a = np.array([1,2,4,2,3,4,1])
s = [1,2]
```

How can I get an array which tells me whether the elements in `s` exist in `a`? 
This is what I'm hoping to get:

```
[True, True, False, True, False, False, True]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use  [`np.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html)

```
>>> np.isin(a,s)

array([ True,  True, False,  True, False, False,  True])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 4, 1])
s = [1, 2]
r = [n in s for n in a]
print(r)  # [True, True, False, True, False, False, True]
```

Answer (score 0):

no numpy, you can do like this

```
a = [1,2,4,2,3,4,1]
s = [1,2]
t = list(map(lambda a: a in s, a))
```

if is `s` is larger, `set` is more effective

```
 a = [1,2,4,2,3,4,1]
 s = set([1,2])
 t = list(map(lambda a: a in s, a))
```

Comment: This is way slower than `np.isin`